# iOS app icon not showing up using flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, appicon

I have tried so many ways and fixes but my app icon still not showing up. I'm using flutter and I used the `flutter_launcher_icons` package but still no use.

Here's my pubspec.yaml dev_depend:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and here the config:

```
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: "AppIcon"
  image_path_ios: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

and here's my AppIcon file
[image]

This is my `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0-1.0.pre.118, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2.5)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This is my Asset Catalog App Icon looks like:

[image]

Comment: Try setting the `ios` attribute to true, and try running it from Xcode.

Comment: @SamiHaddad I'm sorry that didn't work

Comment: In Xcode click on your Project > Target > Build Settings > Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name, what is the value?

Comment: @SamiHaddad check the post, I added a screenshot of the value.

Comment: The value seems to be empty, edit the value of `Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name` and set it to AppIcon, and make sure the 3 values change.

Comment: You can also set this in General > App Icons and Launch Images > App Icons Source

Comment: Have you executed `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` to create the icons per platform?

Comment: @SamiHaddad thanks your fix worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @SamiHaddad, I missed setting the AppIcon to `Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name` in the general section of the Runner file in Xcode. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is worked for me in iOS through manual changes when dependency not worked:-

1. I have generated app icon which required in manual icon changes through site
   (appicon.co)
2. There I got zip file of Image in which I found a folder Assets.xcassets
   after extracting the zip file
3. I found Appicon.appiconset inside the folder Assets.xcassets
4. I replaced that Appicon.appiconset folder to
   iOS/runner/Assets.xcassets/Appicon.appiconset folder
5. Flutter pub get
6. Flutter Run